# Simple CRUD using AngularJS and PHP with JSON File for Storage

Tags: php, angularjs, json, crud

**Before Down voting** (I wanted to implement the CRUD using JSON file and not the Database)

I am using the below code in Angular JS to send the form data to PHP and from PHP I wanted to modify my local JSON file.

I am facing below issues

1. The Form values are going as Null in the JSON file
2. I want to append the array every time user clicks on the register button

   ```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
       <html lang="en">
       <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular.min.js"></script>
       </head>
       <body ng-app="myApp">
        <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
         <form>
          <h2>Register Form</h2>
          <div>
          <label>First Name</label>
          <input type="text" ng-model="firstname" placeholder="First Name"  required="required">
          </div>
       <div>
         <label>Last Name</label>
         <input type="text" ng-model="lastname" placeholder="Last Name" required="required">
       </div>
       <button ng-click='Register()'>Register</button>
       </form>
       <table>
       <tr>
         <th>First Name</th>
         <th>Last Name</th>
       </tr>
       <tr ng-repeat="data in usersData">
         <td>{{data.firstname}}</td>
         <td>{{data.lastname}}</td>
       </tr>
     </table>
   </div>
   <script type="text/javascript">

     var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
     app.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {

       $scope.Register = function () {
         $http.post("misc.php", {
           'firstname': $scope.firstname,
           'lastname': $scope.lastname
         }).success(function (response) {
           $scope.usersData = response.users;
         });
       };
     });
   </script>

    </body>
   </html>
   ```

PHP Code

```
<?php
$file="misc.json";
$json = json_decode(file_get_contents($file),TRUE);
$first = $_POST['firstname'];
$last = $_POST['lastname'];
$json[$user] = array("first" => $first, "last" => $last);
file_put_contents($file, json_encode($json));
?>
```

But Once I Submit I am getting below info in the JSON file
`{"":{"first":null,"last":null}}`

But I wanted to send real values and the JSON format I want as

```
[{
  "first": "John",
  "last": "Anderson"
},
{
  "first": "Mike",
  "last": "Langer"
}]
```

Comment: $user is not set, angular passes data raw so you need to use `file_get_contents('php://input')` in PHP instead of POST, or change the submitted form data in angular. You also need to set your development environment to show all errors. And lastly, your expected output does not match what you will get from `$json[$user] = array(...`, it will give you a json file with `{ "whatever $user is": ["first": "jim", "last": "leirvik"] }`.

Answer (score 1):

I can answer for your 2nd question which is I want to append the array every time user clicks on the register button

Have a local array named $scope.usernames and when you are making a $http.post call inside that success function append it to the $scope.usernames array. Refer the code below.

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
  $scope.usernames=[];
  $scope.Register = function () {
    $http.post("misc.php", {
     'firstname': $scope.firstname,
     'lastname': $scope.lastname
    }).success(function (response) {
        $scope.usernames.push({"firstname":$scope.firstname,"lastname":$scope.lastname});    
        $scope.usersData = response.users;
    });
  };
});
```

I have used PHP long back so i couldn't find about the first error first make sure that it works in angular then make a post call

Comment: sure checking this now!!

Comment: If it is working fine please make this answer as correct. Thanks